# Twilio Conference StatusCallBackEvent not Working

Tags: c#, twilio

I'm making a realtime call application but I'm stuck because twilio conference statuscallbackevent is not working.

[This is my reference.](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/conference#attributes-statusCallbackEvent)

```
var voiceResponse = new VoiceResponse();
var dial = new Dial();
var endConferenceOnExit = bool.Parse(this.Request.QueryString["endConferenceOnExit"]);

var conference = new Conference
{
    Name = Request.QueryString["room"],
    EndConferenceOnExit = endConferenceOnExit
};

var conferenceCallback = UriHelpers.BuildUri(_configurationService.GetCRMTwilioServiceUrl(),
            $"TwilioApi/InboundConference/ConferenceStatusCallBack",
            $"storeId={GetStoreIdParam()}&redisConferenceId={GetRedisConferenceIdParam()}&AgentId={this.Request.QueryString["AgentId"]}");

conference.StatusCallback = new Uri(conferenceCallback);
conference.StatusCallbackEvent = new List<Conference.EventEnum>
    {
        Conference.EventEnum.Start,
        Conference.EventEnum.End,
        Conference.EventEnum.Join,
        Conference.EventEnum.Leave
    };

var conferenceRecordingStatusCallback = UriHelpers.BuildUri(_configurationService.GetCRMTwilioServiceUrl(),
           $"TwilioApi/InboundConference/ConferenceRecordingStatusCallBack",
           $"storeId={GetStoreIdParam()}");

conference.RecordingStatusCallback = new Uri(conferenceRecordingStatusCallback);
conference.Record = Conference.RecordEnum.RecordFromStart;

dial.Append(conference);
voiceResponse.Append(dial);

return TwiML(voiceResponse);
```

I just need the statuscallbackevent to works.

Answer (score 2):

Hi Twilio Evangelist here...

Looks like you may be running into an issue with your statusCallback URL. I'm not sure if the URL is formatted correctly, so that may be one thing worth taking a look at.

By default, Twilio sends a POST request to that URL. You can double check that Twilio is in fact making the request by visiting this URL: https://www.twilio.com/console/voice/conferences/logs. Then in your application I would suggest taking a look to confirm that it is in fact receiving and handling the incoming POST requests.

We solved this on my Twitch stream which you can take a look at here to see how we troubleshooted: https://www.twitch.tv/cldubya. You want to grab the video from 7/30/19

Comment: Thanks man, i know where to go. I forgot the conferences logs